# Agregar Componente a Aplicación desarrollada con SpringFramework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, symfony2

Si han trabajando con Symfony antes entonces conocen sobre los bundles y que puedo agregarle mi propio bundle a una aplicacion hecha con Symfony.
Por ejemplo yo tenia un pequeño sistema de gestion de inventarios, y le agregue un bundle que guardaba las trazas de las operaciones que se ejecutaban y ademas las exportaba a un fichero.

Ahora llevo un tiempo trabajando con SpringFramework y quiero hacer lo mismo:
 A una aplicación de gestión de Colegio desarrollada con Spring quiero añadirle un componente que gestione las trazas de las operaciones que se ejecuten. Por ejemplo: insertar, actualizar o eliminar estudiante, insertar facultades, insertar profesores, etc.

Empecé con el tutorial básico de Spring y poco a poco he construido mi componente. Ahora, cada vez que se ejecute una operación guardo esa información en la base de datos. Mi componente depende también de otras bibliotecas de Java y utiliza Hibernate para persistir en la base de datos. Tiene también sus propias vistas para realizar algunas configuraciones.

Mi pregunta es como puedo integrar mi componente independiente con la aplicacion que ya existe? Me refiero a alguna manera de hacerlo como por ejemplo con los bundles de Symfony.

Les dejo ademas una muestra de la estructura de mi app y la existente, por si aporta mas información a mi pregunta:

```
Estructura Componente de Trazas
src/main/java
    clases controladoras
    clases de la aplicacion
    otras clases utiles
src/test/java
src/main/resources
    vistas
librerias
    jre system library
    dependencias de maven


Estructura Aplicacion de Colegio
src/main/java
    clases controladoras
    clases de la aplicacion
    otras clases utiles
src/test/java
src/main/resources
    vistas
servicios
librerias
    jre system library
    dependencias de maven
```

Answer (score 1):

No me encuentro muy familiarizado con Hibernate, pero éste provee mecanismos para realizar lo que comentas, al igual que doctrine nos provee los llamados callbacks:

@PrePersist
@PreRemove
@PostPersist
@PostRemove
@PreUpdate
@PostUpdate
@PostLoad

Te dejo el link para mas info: [Callbacks Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)

Además de esto existen los llamados Envers que permiten auditar las clases que serán pesistidas, estos permiten mayor configuracion para la udición de las clases. La integración de la API para el manejo de envers es agregar la dependencia a Maven o añadir el jar a tus bibliotecas

Ejemplo envers: [Hibernate Envers](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-use-hibernate-envers-to-audit-data-including-username/)

La ultima que se me ocurre es que lo hagas a traves del **EmptyInterceptor**.

Ejemplo: [EmptyInterceptor](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!!

Comment: El problema de Envers es que te crea una tabla de auditoría por cada tabla/entidad sobre la que se usa. Hay que tener cuidado con un modelo de este tipo porque puede complicar la mantenibilidad de la aplicación y la explotación de la data mediante reportes.

Comment: Exactamente, puse las opciones para que pudiera analizar a su criterio, si no fuera el caso, estaria utilizando el EmptyInterceptor.

Comment: Lo que he usado en otros proyectos es lo que muestras como EmptyInterceptor. En mi opinión, es sencillo de crear y mantener, así como que es una opción flexible para usar en cada tipo de proyecto, y es lo suficientemente transparente para ser una función tipo plug and play.

Comment: Exactamente @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Hola a todos, ya yo tengo implementada la forma de hacer la auditoria, para ello utilizo PostInsertEventListener por ejemplo cuando estoy insertado un objeto. A lo que me refiero con mi pregunta es como integrar mi componente con una aplicacion de gestion. Veran, para yo probar si mi aplicacion realmente funcionaba me invente un "negocio" de una sala de teatro con varias entidades relacionadas entre si. Con estas entidades probe el componente y funciono muy bien, pero el objetivo es que funcione adjunto a otras aplicaciones tambien desarrolladas con SpringFramework.